# Django app does not work when DEBUG=False and using django_heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

I tried deploying my Django website using heroku and used a library called Django-Heroku. When setting my `settings.py` for deployment, it returns `Server Error (500)` when setting
`DEBUG = False`, importing `import django_heroku`  and writing `django_heroku.settings(locals())` at the last line of my `settings.py` file. How can I check the settings set by `django_heroku` that disables my django website for production?

Note: it does not show any error when setting `DEBUG=True` and the django app works fine.

Comment: Have you tried the variable name `DEBUG` instead of `DEBUG_VALUE` ?

Comment: Yes. sorry, my bad. I will edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

i had this problem too, and it will return you that error for specific template, if you try another template you should see that works, so btw, you need check your template for that specific url, maybe you forget some html element to close your tags! check it, fix it and push it again, it will work!

Comment: when setting ```DEBUG=True``` in ```settings.py``` the django app seems to work fine and no errors are showing in the console.

Comment: @A.Sombrio yes right, the problem just in production. so  just do what i wrote, it will work.